# VB6 selecting a Text in a nodes in XML

Tags: xml, vb6

i have a problem on selecting a specific childnodes using VB6 in XML
i would like to select an item in xml using VB6
if i type in the txt1 = "cake" and txt2 = "chocolate"
a messagebox must reply 'item found', IF i chose only cake but
if i choose icecream on txt1, the item was supposed not found.

```
<myxml>
<cake>chocolate</cake>
<cake>Vanilla</cake>
<icecream>Mango</icecream>
<icecream>Strawberry</icecream>
</myxml>
```

please help me with this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the MSXML library (add a reference to "Microsoft XML, v6.0").

It is useful to know the XPath syntax. Using your file as an example, you would want to create an XPath like this:

```
/myxml/cake/[text() = 'chocolate']
```

This selects all elements of type **cake**, which are under **myxml**, and whose internal text is equal to **chocolate**.

Programatically in VB6, you would construct this XPath string on the fly. You would instantiate a DOM object, and load your XML file into it. Use loadxml() if you already have the XML in a string. I am using the selectSingleNode(), because it always returns the first matching node. If you want multiple nodes, use the selectNodes() method instead.

```
Private Sub Command_Click()

    Dim oXmlDoc     As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim oXmlNode    As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    Set oXmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    oXmlDoc.Load "D:\Food.xml"
    Set oXmlNode = oXmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/myxml/" & txt1.Text & "[text() = '" & txt2.Text & "']")

End Sub
```